# Associate label to input with class not id?

Tags: html, forms

I know that you can associate a label with an input using the for and id attributes. However can you use a class and not an id? Thanks

```
<label for="rooms">Number of rooms</label>
<select id="rooms">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Classes are not unique (you can have multiple elements with the same class), so no.

If you want to associate a label to an input without using ID, you can **implicitly** assign it by including said input **inside of the label**:

```
<label>Number of rooms
    <select name="rooms">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

Comment: Support for this isn't as good as it is for the `for` attribute though. (Although it is old-IE that is the major problem and it might be sufficiently dead that that does not matter now).

Comment: Nice - I was not aware of being able to nest the control within the label

Comment: @Quentin: Aye, unless he's making some sort of twisted local application where the environment makes use of IE6 only, there shouldn't be a problem doing it. People out there who use IE6 deserve (IMHO) to see broken websites, with an added notice for them to upgrade. And if they don't want to, you can imagine what they can go do with themselves.

Comment: I agree @Truth, I just wish I could implement something like [this site in Australia (article on UK website The Register)](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/06/14/kogan_ie7_tax/), that actually add an IE7 tax to goods being bought... genius!!

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of when you wouldn't want to use an ID or nest the control:

- I'm creating a BackboneJS application that uses templates. Because the template can be duplicated, it's important to refrain from using IDs, as it will create multiple elements in the DOM with the same ID.
- I'm also using Bootstrap, which will present the control in a different (and undesirable) way if it's wrapped inside the `<label>` element.

At this point, the only solution I can find is to wrap the control element and tweek the default CSS to get the desired output. If someone has a more elegant solution, please chime in.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot use the `class` of an element, because the same class can be used by multiple elements - in which case, which element would the `label` be for?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. The only attribute you can use is the `id` attribute.

It doesn't make sense to use a class (which describes a *group* of related elements) since a label can be associated only with exactly one form control.

Answer (score 3):

you can do this :

```
<label class="col-md-12 input-group input-group-sm">
    <span class="col-sm-5 control-label text-nowrap">Code</span>
    <input class="form-control listen code" type="text" size="15" required/>
</label>
```